# ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture armv7, clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode6, rdio, myspin

I am using two third party SDKs in my application, rdio and mySpin, which was working great. Now I am updating my mySpin in application and getting the following issue:

[image: error]

Comment: Please share where you implementing `CreateDispatchTimer` in both files then I would be able to suggest you better solution.

Answer (score 1):

`CreateDispatchTimer` is declared duplicatly in below both files. Try making their parameters and return type same.

OR

Use different name for both.

Comment: Hi zahid , i don't have any CreateDispatchTimer in both the file.

Comment: one of file is [http://www.rdio.com/media/static/developer/ios/docs/_r_d_player_8h_source.html

Comment: Do you have access to source of any of both frameworks..?? If yes then there would a static block OR any var with name CreateDispatchTimer. 

Also happens if you accidentally #import a .m file instead of the .h!

Comment: I already verified these things #import a .m file instead of the .h! , I din't did any mistake like this as well as I am using mySpin framework also in application but no variable name or method name CreateDispatchTimer.

Comment: You're using a static library (.a file) which already includes some classes that you include into the project.

For fixing any of those cases, check the linker error and look for the .o files that are duplicated (sample: Reachability.o).

Then go to the build phases -> compile sources and search the specified files, if any one appears twice delete one of them, if only appears once it means that the file is also included in one of the static libraries added to your project. Delete it from your list of sources to be compiled and try again.